# Error when opening an sql connection: 'MyConnection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, connection-string

I have seen this problem in many posts, but cannot fix.. I'm trying to connect to a table in my SQL DB, using visual Studio 2015 (C#), and keep on getting an error.
This is my code (note: the connection string was taken from appsettings.json file):

```
 string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet5-LicenseTool-b66aeae7-0f53-4987-8e86-6fba8a7f5e16;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
 using (SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
     // some code here 
 }
```

...
when I run I get an error of:

> 'MyConnection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

See attachments of error and of server data - You can see I'm connected and I have correct parameters.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJIE9.jpg)

[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej3FB.png)

Comment: Try Clean solution and rebuild....?

Comment: Did you try simplyfing you connection string? IE: Remove everything after the _Integrated Security=True;_  part

Comment: the Open command seems to work now (thought it didnt yesterday...) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your error message clearly states `Invalid operation. The connection is closed.`. This means that you didn't `Open()` the connection.
Use this:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet5-LicenseTool-b66aeae7-0f53-4987-8e86-6fba8a7f5e16;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
using (SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    MyConnection.Open();
    // some code here 
}
```

Comment: funny - I did that yesterday and it didnt work. Just tried again - and it seems to work! Thanks !!